# Convert sql query to Doctrine2 query using CreateQuery

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have the following mysql query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN t2.user1=1 THEN t2.user2 ELSE t2.user1 END AS userId
    FROM
        t AS t2
    WHERE 1 IN (t2.user1,t2.user2)
    AND t2.[status]=1
) as tbl
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT
        NULL
    FROM
        t
    WHERE 2 IN (t.user1,t.user2)
    AND tbl.userId=(CASE WHEN t.user1=2 THEN t.user2 ELSE t.user1 END)
    AND t.[status]=1
)
```

It works fine but i am not able to convert it to Doctrine2 query .

Any idea how?

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c792/11

[EDIT]
I have used Native SQL to execute the query.

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult('myProject\DataBundle\Entity\Friend', 'f');

    $sql= '
    SELECT
             *
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                CASE WHEN t2.user1=2 THEN t2.user2 ELSE t2.user1 END AS userId
            FROM friends AS t2 
            WHERE 2 IN (t2.user1,t2.user2) 
            AND t2.status=1 
        ) as tbl 
        WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 
            NULL 
        FROM 
            friends as t
        WHERE 3 IN (t.user1,t.user2) 
        AND tbl.userId=(CASE WHEN t.user1=3 THEN t.user2 ELSE t.user1_id END) 
        AND t.isFriendOrFollower=1 )';

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createNativeQuery($sql,$rsm);
```

But there is no results being displayed.

Comment: Since you are simply selecting scalars, did you consider using simply NativeSQL ? http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

Comment: @Ocramius i have added native sql as you suggested. but still no result

Comment: you will need to map a scalar result since you are selecting only a single column

Comment: @Ocramius can you please tell me what do you mean by scalar in this context?

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#scalar-results

Comment: @Ocramius i tried the scalar result but still no result. Did i miss anything?

Comment: Please update your question with the current code.

Comment: Finally found a solution to my problem. Thank you @Ocramius for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a easier way to do that using dbal.

1: you have to get the connection

```
$conn=$this->container->get('database_connection');
```

2: write the query

```
$sql= '
    SELECT
             *
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                CASE WHEN t2.user1=2 THEN t2.user2 ELSE t2.user1 END AS userId
            FROM friends AS t2 
            WHERE 2 IN (t2.user1,t2.user2) 
            AND t2.status=1 
        ) as tbl 
        WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 
            NULL 
        FROM 
            friends as t
        WHERE 3 IN (t.user1,t.user2) 
        AND tbl.userId=(CASE WHEN t.user1=3 THEN t.user2 ELSE t.user1_id END) 
        AND t.isFriendOrFollower=1 )';
```

3: execute the query.

```
$rows = $conn->fetchAll($sql);
```

Done, problem solved.